# unable to return a 2-dimensional array from a method

Tags: java, arrays, return

I had to write a program that find the largest element in an array. The user is prompted to enter the number of rows and columns, then prompted to enter the numbers in the rows and columns.

This array is then passed to a method where each number in every column of every row is compared and when the largest number is found the location is then moved to a field which, hopefully, return from the method.

It is not working.  Here is my code.. I am sure that it is something silly, but what I can't figure it out.  I think that it might have to with the 'a' in calling the method.

- I define 'a' with `double[][] a = new double[r][c];`
- I call and pass to the method with `int[] find = locateLargest(a);`
- I tried to use all 3 of these as the return statement:

  ```
  // return largest;
  return largest[indxrow][indxcol];     
  // return [indxrow][indxcol];
  ```

How can I fix my code?

```
void main(String[] args) {
    java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number of rows and columns of the array");   
    int r = input.nextInt();
    int c = input.nextInt();

    double[][] rowCol = new double[r][c];
    double[][] a = new double[r][c];

    System.out.println("Enter the array");
    for (int rows = 0; rows < rowCol.length; rows++) { 
        for (int cols = 0; cols < rowCol[rows].length; cols++) {
            rowCol[rows][cols] = input.nextDouble();
            a[rows][cols] = rowCol[rows][cols];
            int[] find = locateLargest(a);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("The location of the largest element is at (" + a[0]  + ", " + a[1] + ")");
}   

public static int[] locateLargest(double[][] a) {
    double largest = 0;
    int indxrow;
    int indxcol;

    for (int lcol = 0; lcol < a[0].length; lcol++ ) {
        largest = a[0][lcol];
        indxcol = lcol;
    }   

    for (int lrow = 1;  lrow  <  a.length;  lrow++)  { 
        for (int lcol = 0;  lcol  <  a[lrow].length;  lcol++) 
            if (a[lrow][lcol] > largest) {  
                largest = a[lrow][lcol];
                indxrow = lrow;
            }
        }
        //  return largest;
        return largest[indxrow][indxcol];     
        //return [indxrow][indxcol];
    }  
}
```

Comment: What actually is happening?  is it throwing a `DoesNotWorkException`?

Comment: What is locateLargest supposed to return?

Answer (score 0):

In order to return an int[] (as you specified in `public static int[] locateLargest(double[][] a)`) in your method, you should use

```
return a[lrow];
```

because `a` is an `int[][]`, so a[a_certain_position] will be an `int[]`, i.e. what you are looking for.

EDIT:
This assuming that `a` was an int[][], but I noticed you defined it as a double[][]. Keep in mind (int[])a[lrow] cast is not possible in Java, so I would suggest you to change your method to return a double[] instead, like this:

```
public static double[] locateLargest(double[][] a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to return a `double`, when the actual return type of the method is an `int[]`

from how your code looks, it seems that you mean to return the largest number in the array.. In that case you should return a `double`, since your array you pass in is a `double[][]`

```
public static double locateLargest(double[][] a) {
    double largest = 0;

    for (int lcol = 0; lcol < a[0].length; lcol++) {
        largest = a[0][lcol];
    }

    for (int lrow = 1; lrow < a.length; lrow++) {
        for (int lcol = 0; lcol < a[lrow].length; lcol++)
        if (a[lrow][lcol] > largest) {
            largest = a[lrow][lcol];
        }
    }
    return largest;
}
```